# .htaccess redirect with parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

Hi I want to convert url in the below format `domain.com/specificurl/param1/param2/param3` to `domain.com/specificurl?par1=param1&par2=param2&par3=param3` using .htaccess. Please share the RewriteRule for the same.

I tried this `RewriteRule ^phppage/(*)/(*)/(*) phppage?par1=$1&par2=$2&par3=$3` but not working.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please put a bit more afford in your question and add details about what exactly you want and what you have tried so far. This is no page where you "order" code

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in regex but this works.

```
RewriteRule /specificurl/([\w]*)/([\w]*)/([\w]*)$ /specificurl.php?par1=$1&par2=$2&par3=$3  [R=301,L]
```

I'll refactor to best answer soon. This wont work if any of the params are missing.

Comment: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
RewriteRule ^one/([\w]+)/([\w]+)/([\w]+)$ one?par1=$1&par2=$2&par3=$3  [R]` is showing **Internal Server Error**

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php` this will change url url to `domain.com/specificurl/param1/param2/param3\.php`

Comment: I changed .htaccess file to `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule specificurl/([\w]+)/([\w]+)/([\w]+)$ specificurl.php?par1=$1&par2=$2&par3=$3  [R]` but now when i cal `domain/specificurl/1/2/3` it change url to `domain/C:/wamp/www/domain/specificurl.php?par1=1&par2=2&par3=3` any mistake in my Rule?

Comment: _The requested URL /specificurl/1/2/3 was not found on this server._ :(

Comment: I have fixed my answer.

Comment: I changed the .htaccess file as `RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /specificurl/([\w]+)/([\w]+)/([\w]+)$ /specificurl.php?par1=$1&par2=$2&par3=$3  [R=301,L]` but result is _The requested URL /specificurl/1/2/3 was not found on this server._ :(

Comment: May be some other rule is blocking this rule. Same rule works in my machine. you may want to check your rules. ref: https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489

Comment: BTW, my .htaccess file holds: `
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-d
RewriteRule /specificurl/([\w]+)/([\w]+)/([\w]+)$ /specificurl.php?par1=$1&par2=$2&par3=$3  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /index.php?$1  [NC,L,QSA]`

Comment: Tried with above mentioned .htaccess codes, but same error is shown